# Select query for 3 joining tables

Tags: mysql, sql, join, select

I have 2 tables, the table flight and the table departure with the following

```
Table flight:

flightnr|   dest    |   start
        |           |
--------------------------------
        |           |
LH100   |   ATL     |   FRA
LH102   |   DXB     |   FRA
LH103   |   ORD     |   FRA
LH104   |   HND     |   FRA
LH105   |   LHR     |   FRA
LH106   |   LAX     |   FRA
LH107   |   HKG     |   FRA
LH108   |   CDG     |   FRA
LH109   |   DFW     |   FRA
LH110   |   IST     |   FRA
LH200   |   ATL     |   LHR
LH201   |   PEK     |   LHR
LH202   |   DXB     |   LHR
LH203   |   ORD     |   LHR
LH204   |   FRA     |   LHR
```

and the other table is

```
Table departure:

flightnr|   date        |   sign
        |               |
---------------------------------------
        |               |
LH-100  |   2018-01-10  |   D-ABBL
LH-100  |   2018-02-10  |   D-ABBL
LH-100  |   2018-03-10  |   D-ABBL
LH-100  |   2018-04-10  |   D-ABBL
LH-100  |   2018-05-10  |   D-ABBL
LH-100  |   2018-06-10  |   D-ABBL
LH-100  |   2018-07-10  |   D-ABBK
LH-100  |   2018-08-10  |   D-ABBK
LH-102  |   2018-02-10  |   D-ABBB
LH-102  |   2018-04-10  |   D-ABBB
LH-102  |   2018-06-10  |   D-ABBB
LH-103  |   2018-09-10  |   D-ABBB
LH-104  |   2018-03-10  |   D-ABBB
LH-104  |   2018-05-10  |   D-ABBB
LH-104  |   2018-07-10  |   D-ABBB
LH-104  |   2018-09-10  |   D-ABBB
LH-105  |   2018-01-10  |   D-ABBB
LH-105  |   2018-02-10  |   D-ABBB
LH-105  |   2018-03-10  |   D-ABBB
LH-200  |   2018-01-10  |   D-ABCA
LH-200  |   2018-02-10  |   D-ABCA
LH-201  |   2018-03-10  |   D-ABCA
LH-201  |   2018-05-10  |   D-ABBR
LH-202  |   2018-05-10  |   D-ABCA
LH-202  |   2018-09-10  |   D-ABCA
LH-203  |   2018-04-10  |   D-ABCA
LH-203  |   2018-05-10  |   D-ABCA
LH-203  |   2018-06-10  |   D-ABCC
LH-204  |   2018-01-10  |   D-ABBF
LH-204  |   2018-03-10  |   D-ABBI
LH-204  |   2018-08-10  |   D-ABBM
```

So now I want to select the lines which give me the possibility to fly from the iata 'FRA' to 'PEK' which is not possible in 1 departure, because there is no direct flight from 'FRA' to 'PEK' in the table departure.

As a customer I have to fly from 'FRA' to 'LHR' first so I can fly from 'LHR' to 'PEK' after this.

My problem now is, that I really don't know how to select the lines which give me the possibilities of flying from 'FRA' to 'PEK'. The output should be something like this:

```
   date    | flightnr | start | change_over_dest |   date    | flightnr | change_over_start | dest
------------+--------+-------+--------------+------------+--------+---------------+------
 2018-03-10| LH-105   | FRA   | LHR              | 2018-03-10| LH-201   | LHR               | PEK
 2018-03-10| LH-105   | FRA   | LHR              | 2018-05-10| LH-201   | LHR               | PEK
```

I already tryed many different versions of using JOINS between the 2 tables (used 2 JOINS to join flight to itself and then departure) but none of them nearly worked in a proper way.

Hopefully I described my problem in a clear way and you guys can help me out.

Greetings

Zeroza

Comment: Your expected output does not make complete sense to me.  Do you really consider a 2 month layover in London Heathrow airport to be acceptable to any actual passenger?  It would seem to me that the dates should match.  However, there are issues with changing time zones etc., so this problem could get complicated.

Comment: I'm sorry for the wrong date-format in this example, these dates should be the 3. October 2018 and the 5. October 2018 and not the 10. March and the 10. May.

Additionally the timezones are unimportant since these are example-datas and it is assumed, that the flight from LHR to PEK will start after the flight from FRA to LHR landed.

Comment: Don't apologize. Just fix it!

Comment: What have you done so far???  Have you even attempted at all?

Comment: "I have tryed many different version using JOINS between 2 tables".  I don't see any query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can try doing a self join on the `flight` table, with the condition that the first destination is the start of the second route.  In addition, we can restrict the starting and final destination cities.  Note that we also join to each `flight` table the `departure` table, to bring in the dates of departure.

```
SELECT
    d1.date AS date_start,
    f1.flightnr AS flightnr_start,
    f1.start AS first_start,
    f1.dest AS change_over_dest,
    d2.date AS date_end,
    f2.flightnr AS flightnr_end,
    f2.start AS last_start,
    f2.dest AS change_over_end
FROM flight f1
INNER JOIN departure d1
    ON f1.flightnr = d1.flightnr
INNER JOIN flight f2
    ON f1.dest = f2.start
INNER JOIN departure d2
    ON f2.flightnr = d2.flightnr AND d1.date = d2.date
WHERE
    f1.start = 'FRA' AND f2.dest = 'PEK';
```

I did not bother building a demo around your full sample data set, because it is full of typos.  Instead, I just setup a simple demo, below, which seems to be working.

### Demo

Answer (score 0):

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS fight;

CREATE TABLE flight
(flightnr CHAR(5) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
,destination CHAR(3) NOT NULL
,start CHAR(3) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO flight VALUES
('LH100','ATL','FRA'),
('LH102','DXB','FRA'),
('LH103','ORD','FRA'),
('LH104','HND','FRA'),
('LH105','LHR','FRA'),
('LH106','LAX','FRA'),
('LH107','HKG','FRA'),
('LH108','CDG','FRA'),
('LH109','DFW','FRA'),
('LH110','IST','FRA'),
('LH200','ATL','LHR'),
('LH201','PEK','LHR'),
('LH202','DXB','LHR'),
('LH203','ORD','LHR'),
('LH204','FRA','LHR');

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS departure;

CREATE TABLE departure
(flightnr CHAR(5) NOT NULL
,date DATE NOT NULL
,sign CHAR(6) NOT NULL
,PRIMARY KEY(flightnr,date)
);

INSERT INTO departure VALUES
('LH100','2018-10-01','D-ABBL'),
('LH100','2018-10-02','D-ABBL'),
('LH100','2018-10-03','D-ABBL'),
('LH100','2018-10-04','D-ABBL'),
('LH100','2018-10-05','D-ABBL'),
('LH100','2018-10-06','D-ABBL'),
('LH100','2018-10-07','D-ABBK'),
('LH100','2018-10-08','D-ABBK'),
('LH102','2018-10-02','D-ABBB'),
('LH102','2018-10-04','D-ABBB'),
('LH102','2018-10-06','D-ABBB'),
('LH103','2018-10-09','D-ABBB'),
('LH104','2018-10-03','D-ABBB'),
('LH104','2018-10-05','D-ABBB'),
('LH104','2018-10-07','D-ABBB'),
('LH104','2018-10-09','D-ABBB'),
('LH105','2018-10-01','D-ABBB'),
('LH105','2018-10-02','D-ABBB'),
('LH105','2018-10-03','D-ABBB'),
('LH200','2018-10-01','D-ABCA'),
('LH200','2018-10-02','D-ABCA'),
('LH201','2018-10-03','D-ABCA'),
('LH201','2018-10-05','D-ABBR'),
('LH202','2018-10-05','D-ABCA'),
('LH202','2018-10-09','D-ABCA'),
('LH203','2018-10-04','D-ABCA'),
('LH203','2018-10-05','D-ABCA'),
('LH203','2018-10-06','D-ABCC'),
('LH204','2018-10-01','D-ABBF'),
('LH204','2018-10-03','D-ABBI'),
('LH204','2018-10-08','D-ABBM');

SELECT f1.flightnr
     , f1.start
     , d1.date startdate
     , f2.flightnr transferflightnr
     , f2.start transferlocation
     , d2.date transferdate
     , f2.destination 
  FROM flight f1 
  JOIN departure d1 
    ON d1.flightnr = f1.flightnr 
  JOIN flight f2 
    ON f2.start = f1.destination 
  JOIN departure d2 
    ON d2.flightnr = f2.flightnr 
   AND d2.date >= d1.date 
 WHERE f2.destination = 'pek' 
   AND f1.start = 'fra';
+----------+-------+------------+------------------+------------------+--------------+-------------+
| flightnr | start | startdate  | transferflightnr | transferlocation | transferdate | destination |
+----------+-------+------------+------------------+------------------+--------------+-------------+
| LH105    | FRA   | 2018-10-01 | LH201            | LHR              | 2018-10-03   | PEK         |
| LH105    | FRA   | 2018-10-02 | LH201            | LHR              | 2018-10-03   | PEK         |
| LH105    | FRA   | 2018-10-03 | LH201            | LHR              | 2018-10-03   | PEK         |
| LH105    | FRA   | 2018-10-01 | LH201            | LHR              | 2018-10-05   | PEK         |
| LH105    | FRA   | 2018-10-02 | LH201            | LHR              | 2018-10-05   | PEK         |
| LH105    | FRA   | 2018-10-03 | LH201            | LHR              | 2018-10-05   | PEK         |
+----------+-------+------------+------------------+------------------+--------------+-------------+
```